# Why is $e^{g(x)} = \pi$ where $g(x)$ is holomorphic in Weierstrass factorization of sine function?

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

Why is $e^{g(x)} = \pi$ where $g(x)$ is holomorphic in Weierstrass factorization of sine function? I just can't get why it's true.

Comment: What is $g(x)$?

Comment: Edited my question. Sorry.

Comment: Do you mean the entire function factor $\color{Blue}\pi$ in the Weierstrass product factorization $$\sin(\pi x)=\color{Blue}{\pi} x\prod_{n\ne0}\left(1-\frac{x}{n}\right)~?$$ To see why that factor is simply $\pi$, consider $\displaystyle\lim\limits_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}{x}=1$.

Comment: A good reference for this stuff is Whittaker and Watson's Modern Analysis 7.4,5,6 where the case of $\sin z$ is treated before the general Weierstrass theorem is proven.

Comment: @anon The limit consideration does not rule out the factor $\pi x e^{2013 x^2}$.

Comment: @user75064 Slipped my mind. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of textbook material than Math.SE material. The entire Chapter 6 of [Complex Made Simple](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=GSM-97) by David C. Ullrich is devoted to the factorization of sine. He gives three different, and very detailed, proofs. Luckily, this chapter is in the [free preview](http://www.ams.org/bookstore/pspdf/gsm-97-prev.pdf) of the book.